# Strange error by a testing for TCP connection timeout with the cable unplugged

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, tcp

I've experienced some random TCP disconnection in production environment: A high load server in Windows Embedded and a client in Windows XP sit in a LAN, connected by long lived TCP via a Switcher, most data flow is from server to client.

The **server side** core code is straight forward and I simplified as:

```
 try
 {
      TcpListener tcpListener = new TcpListener(System.Net.IPAddress.Any, 8190);
      tcpListener.Start();
      var tcpClient = tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient();
      var ns = tcpClient.GetStream();
      ns.Write(bytes);
 }
 catch (Exception ex)
 { 

 }
```

the random exception in that `catch` is:

> System.IO.IOException: Unable to write data to the transport connection: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.

I understand this exception as client has no response (some underlying TCP level ACK or sth) to certain TCP request from server, but the problem is in some cases, the exception just raised up in 4 or 5 seconds from that `ms.WriteTo(ns);` called.

**So the question 1**, since I didn't specify any timeout values for `TcpClient` object, why the Write timeout so short? possible the TCP have the dynamic timeout settings when connection established(based on Round Trip Time or sth), but should be longer(I guess).

==============================

I then write a small program to simulate the situation, I periodically send data from server to client, suddenly I **unplug** the cable in client machine, what surprise me is the `ns.Write(bytes)` in server side still can be called smoothly like an `async` call does, but not the expected blocking call and exception would pop up right after I unplugged the cable.

SO the question 2, if the `Write` behaves like this, then we never know what data has been successfully send to other side, and this is why we use TCP.

===============================

with cable unplugged, I still keep `Write` data, I noticed when the data I send reached certain amount (probably 100 bytes), and then the offline time reached 30 seconds, exception raised and also confused me:

> System.IO.IOException:
>   Unable  to write data to the transport connection: An existing
>   connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. --->
>   System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was
>   forcibly closed by the remote host    at
>   System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Send(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32
>   size, So cketFlags socketFlags)    at
>   System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset,
>   Int32 size)

**If I just send few bytes, there's no exception at all forever.** 
SO the question 3, TCP data failed to reach other side might not raise any notification in sender side? 
And the question 4, who closed the connection in the exception described? I expected a time out exception here since client side totally disappear.

Comment: I can answer only (2): You indeed never know that data was received with TCP except if the other side sends you a confirmation. How could you possibly find out otherwise if all packets go into a black hole?

Comment: @usr so we would never know which data has been send successfully to other side, then have to implement a mechanism in application level if needed? this really confused me for the concept of TCP.

Comment: Yes. I don't know why no TCP stack I know of does not expose ACK information. It seems to me TCP *could* provide this service but the OS does not expose it.